# how can I debug binutils to check assembler options

Tags: c, assembly

how to debug gnu binutils
I want to check code flow for assembler option 
I have following assembler option

```
/gas/as-new --statistics -o dump.o a.s
```

how can I debug binutils. I have ddd debugger and I have also used -g option in the configuration option which will give me debugging information but what next ??

Comment: Do you want to run `as` itself in a debugger, or your code that you assemble with `as`? And what do you mean by "code flow for assembler option"? Can you please elaborate on the *actual* problem you have? *Why* do you want to "debug binutils"?

Comment: I want to see what functions or what code assembler will call internally when assembler options are given

Comment: You *do* know that binutils is open-source, and that the full source code is available? And I still would like to know *why* you want this? Is it plain curiosity? Or is there some underlying problem you want help figuring out? If it's some other problem you want to solve, then perhaps you should ask about *that* instead?

Comment: actually there are many assembler options added in gnu 2.27 as compared to gnu 2.26. so I want to provide support of these options in our binutils hence I want to know internals of how assembler options are supported so that I can give support to new options in our binutils. can you help me ?

Comment: Do you mean you have your own "binutils"? That you have a project where a certain version is mandated and you can not update to a new version?  If you want to *backport* (look up the term) some features of a newer version to an older version, you need to know how to do it yourself, or be able to pay someone to do it for you, it's *way* to broad a topic for SO.

Comment: What do you mean "what next"?  Is there something about binutils that makes it different from debugging any other C program?  Set a breakpoint, `run --statistics -o dump.o a.s` from inside gdb / ddd, then single step.